# Java installation using shellscript

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, centos

I am new to shell scripting and I am looking for a way to install java 1.8 on centos machine such that if java 1.8 is already exists then script will skip the installation AND if any other version of Java exists then it will install 1.8 and will use 1.8 only.
Help here would be really appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_VER=$(java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | egrep "\S+\s+version" | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d '"')
        if [ "${JAVA_VER}" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "java $JAVA_VER already installed. Skipping installation..."
  else
      echo "Installing java..."
      yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y
      echo "java installed!"
        java -version
        echo "----------------------------------------------------"
  fi
```

Comment: what is the output of `java -version` since I do not have java installed

Comment: @ShakibaMoshir iopenjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can extractthe version `major.minor` and check against it

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# checking by java -version
JAVA_VERSION=$(java -version);

# or set it manually for test purposes
# JAVA_VERSION=1.7

# extract major.minor
JAVA_VERSION_INSTALLED=$(perl -lne  '/\d+.\d+/ && print $&' <<< $JAVA_VERSION);

case $JAVA_VERSION_INSTALLED in
    1.8 )
        echo "$JAVA_VERSION_INSTALLED already installed";
        echo "nothing do do";
        exit 0;
    ;;
    1.* )
        echo "you Java is old, trying to install new one";
        # you can do the business here with yum, app-get, etc
    ;;
    * )
        echo "unknown version";
        exit 1;

    ;;
esac
```

#### NOTE

- I have not `java` installed, the pattern matching is based on what you commented
- update the case accordingly